# Recommended way to "load" javascript file dependencies?

Tags: javascript

I have a priorityQueue class that depends on a set of heap functions being loaded.
Currently they're in separate files, priorityQueue.js and fheap.js.
I would like to do

```
<script src="priorityQueue.js"></script>
```

and have the fheap.js file automatically loaded (order doesn't matter). Furthermore, I'd like a method that cascades (ie dijkstra.js loads priorityQueue loads fheap).

Currently each file just loads its dependencies by injecting  elements at end of . Is there a better way to achieve the same result, and what should I watch out for with the current method?

Comment: Should probably use js [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules), as explained e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/950146).

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file) and answer for some good discussion.   The short answer i believe is use jQuery because then you can do this sort of thing:

```
$.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){
  alert("Script loaded and executed.");
  // here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script
});
```

ian.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use a library to do it for you.  It is great when you don't have to reinvent the wheel and you can use something that is solid and tested.  There is [jQuery Lazy Plugin Loader](http://unwrongest.com/projects/lazy/) and [ensure](http://ensure.codeplex.com/) just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be late for you, but for those looking for the same answer, there's a lightweight JS dependency loader on git called deploader-js (also available through `bower install deploader-js`) for exactly this usecase:

https://github.com/MikeSpock/deploader-js